# How to use jade to get data sent by res.render

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using express and am using res.render like this:

```
 res.render('myurl', {
      data: {
        account: escape(JSON.stringify(outcome.account)),
        user: escape(JSON.stringify(outcome.user))
    });
```

JADE file:

```
  script.
    -console.log('hi');
    -console.log(data.user)
```

How do I access this data on a Jade file. I know I have to use some sort of data binding but am not sure what to do exactly? Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You just use `data.account` and `data.user` as the variable names in your template.

Comment: I keep getting data is undefined. console.log(data.account) gives me data is undefined. How do I access it correctly?

Comment: That is how you access it correctly. It works for me, so there must be something else wrong...

Answer (score 1):

use data.account and data.user to access data. 
If you're getting undefined, might be it will render first and then extracting data. (As it is asynchronous) This can be one of the reason, why you're getting undefined output.